# Using a react app without rendering a html piece

Tags: reactjs

I come from Angularjs 1.6.x . What is i need is that using a react app without rendering a html piece like

```
ReactDOM.render(null, document.querySelector("#container"));
```

this is my .container that contain some html tags that want to use my react app model and logic in it:

```
<div id="contact">
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="send">
    <div v-if="errorMessage.length" class="alert alert-danger">
      {{ errorMessage }}
    </div>
    <div :class="{ 'form-group': true, 'has-error': errors.has('name'), 'has-success': name.length && !errors.has('name') }">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input autofocus v-model="name" v-validate="'required|min:5'" class="form-control" name="name" type="text" />
      <span  class="text-danger">{{ errors.first('name') }}</span>
    </div>
    <div :class="{ 'form-group': true, 'has-danger': errors.has('email'), 'has-success': email.length && !errors.has('email') }">
      <label for="email">E-mail</label>
      <input v-model="email" v-validate="'required|email'" class="form-control" name="email" type="text" />
      <span  class="text-danger">{{ errors.first('email') }}</span>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </form>
</div>
```

FYI I can achieve this scenario with Vuejs.

My question is can I achieve this scenario with React ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ReactDOM.render(null,document.querySelector('#container'))
```

You can do this.

Comment: Hi @illiteraterwriter . What that you mention is a typo missing and not the answer of my question.

Comment: Yes you can achieve that scenario with React. Wasn't that your question?

Comment: Yes, that is my question but how I can achieve it?